# Carousel or Slider with md-card inside Angular Material

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, carousel

I want to build a carousel/slider with md-card inside, not an image or video. The md-card can have an image, video inside it though.

The best example I have come across is Google's Snapping Carousel which shows the results for tweets that are horizontally scrollable.

[image]

I also found Ninja-slider to be helpful and working. The problem is though that it does not work on the project I want to include it in and it requires a license. It does not show any errors also, but is not working also. Here is [the codepen](http://codepen.io/robotboy1000/pen/WxEkNP) and an image below.

[image]

Then, I tried to use Bootstrap's carousel but it shows a directive-controller error where I have applied all possible solutions with no successful outcome. Then I used [Bootstrap's Angular Carousel](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which I think has its own bugs as it sometimes does not work at all and when it does, it is never seamless.

Finally, I came across [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) and it also does the job. [Here is the codepen](http://codepen.io/robotboy1000/pen/JKyQpm).

```
<div class="carousel js-flickity">
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <md-content class="md-padding" layout-xs="column" layout="row">
```

But even this doesn't look perfect and also requires a license.
[image]

What is the closest alternative to what Google does (as shown above)? 
Also, I don't want to have jQuery in this (if possible). 
PS: I have removed codepen links because of obvious reasons.

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: nope, I used what I had made https://codepen.io/robotboy1000/pen/JKyQpm